# SFDX occasionally fails decryption on all my authorized orgs, causing me to re-auth them all

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin

I have been using SFDX for the last couple years as a way to log into seperate orgs easier. Every once and a while, I will load up terminal and try to log into an org, only to get this error:

```
ERROR running force:org:open:  Failed to decipher auth data. reason: Unsupported state or unable to authenticate data.
```

If I re-auth, the org will show as connected, and I will be able to open the org.

But why does this happen? Has this happened to anyone else? Is there any fix you have found besides just deleting the cache and re-authing all orgs?

Here is also a picture of my force:org:list when this happens:
[image]

Comment: Did the password on your computer change during that time? That could have messed something up with the system keychain for a brief period

Comment: I can confirm that it has not. I haven't changed my password in years.